# No puedo borrar un elemento ionc

Tags: html, typescript, ionic, ionic-framework

muy buenas soy nueva en ionic y, tengo un problema, cuando agrego un elemento, en este caso una visita X, lo agrega, pero cuando quiero borrarlo, si borra el elemento, pero no desaparece de la pantalla, solo aparece "elemento borrado pero no desaparece", si me pudiera ayudar se los agradecería mucho., este es mi código:

```
 async lanzarMenu() {

let guardarBorrarBtn;
  guardarBorrarBtn = {
    text: 'Borrar visita',
    icon: 'trash',
    cssClass: 'action-dark',
    handler: () => {
      console.log('Borrar visita');
      this.dataLocalVisitaService.borrarVisita(this.visita);
      
    }
  };

 borrarVisita(visita: Visita) {
this.visitas = this.visitas.filter(vis => vis.idvisita !== visita.idvisita)
this.storage.set(this.construyeNombreEtiqueta(), this.visitas);
this.dataLocalService.presentToast('Visita borrada');
```

}

[image: Adjunto imagen de como se muestra:]

Comment: Qué código usas para eliminar el elemento?

Comment: borrarVisita(visita: Visita) {
    this.visitas = this.visitas.filter(vis => vis.idvisita !== visita.idvisita)
    this.storage.set(this.construyeNombreEtiqueta(), this.visitas);
    this.dataLocalService.presentToast('Visita borrada');
  }

Comment: por favor, bonito día

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que inicialmente `this.visitas` contiene el arreglo original y la vista hace referencia a el. Por eso al agregar elementos la vista se actualiza, porque `push()` modifica el arreglo original.

En cambio cuando se intenta eliminar usando `filter()` eso provoca que `this.visitas` tenga un nuevo arreglo y la vista no se actualiza porque la vista sigue apuntando al arreglo original y ese no se ha modificado.

Para poder borrar elementos y que se actualice la vista se debe hacer sobre el arreglo original, removiéndolo desde ahí, por ejemplo usando el método `slice()`.

```
borrarVisita(visita: Visita) {
    // se obtiene el índice del objeto filtrando por su id
    let index = this.visitas.findIndex(v => v.idVisita == visita.id);
    // se elimina ese elemento del arreglo orignal y la vista
    // se actualiza
    this.visitas.slice(index,1);
    
    this.storage.set(this.construyeNombreEtiqueta(), this.visitas);
    this.dataLocalService.presentToast('Visita borrada');
    }
```